# MS Dynamics 365 Business Process Flow Visual Designer Output

Tags: entity, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, visualdesigner

I have created a "project"-entity Business Process Flow in MS Dynamics 365 Visual Process Designer. How do I now output it into a live project interface which users would interact with? I get the sense this can either be done in Sales-> Opportunities or Project Service Automation -> New Project but no areas I see seem to mention my active business flow to output from.

[image: Screen of activated project process I created]

Other Microsoft resources (examples linked below) describe the Process creation steps fully but skip the "export" step and immediately drop into the live project interface.

[image: Example output to project live project interface I want to output my process to, given by Hitachi]

Research links:

A: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/mt826697.aspx

B: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn531067.aspx

C: https://us.hitachi-solutions.com/blog/dynamics-365-roadmap-a-complete-guide-to-dynamics-365-business-process-flows/

D: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customize/create-business-process-flow

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer to my own question ... after I deactivated all the other default "project"-entity processes (specifically the standard "Project Phases" process), Dynamics Project Service  automatically chose my active custom process when I created a new project.

It seems odd that only one active process per entity type is allowed, and there are no choices for user to output from other templates.